# What does the sentence "The collective noun is a terror of tyrannosaurs" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

The following is the opening line of [an article](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/jul/23/tyrannosaurs-hunted-packs-tracks-canada) titled *Researchers find first sign that tyrannosaurs hunted in packs*:

> **The collective noun is a terror of tyrannosaurs**: a pack of the prehistoric predators, moving and hunting in numbers, for prey that faced the fight of its life.

What does the first sentence "The collective noun is a terror of tyrannosaurs" mean? I know what a collective noun is. But, how can "a terror of tyrannosaurs" be a collective noun?

Later in the article, the word "terror" is mentioned again.

> The footprints were so well-preserved that even the contours of the animals' skin were visible. "You start wondering what it would have been like to have been there when the tracks were made. The word is **terror**. I wouldn't want to meet them in a dark alley at night," McCrea said.

I guess this may be a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, groups or packs of animals often have traditional, strange names, like "a school of fish" or "a parliament of owls"

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal

So in your first sentence, the author alludes to that tradition by introducing a new term for a group of tyrannosaurs - a "terror of tyrannosaurs". It follows the pattern of traditional naming, and - as the second sentence notes - it's an apt description of what you'd be feeling when facing multiple tyrannosaurs working together to hunt you down.